# Electron: How to share BrowserWindow instance across multiple files?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to have a js file let's say `window.js` that is responsible for creating and exporting an unique instance of `BrowserWindow` so that I can reuse this instance across multiple js files.

Until now I tried this:

```
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
    
    let window = null;
   
    const createWindow = () => {
      if (window) return;
      window = new BrowserWindow({
      minWidth: 820,
      minHeight: 620,
      width: 820,
      height: 620,
      resizable: false,
      webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
        enableRemoteModule: true,
      },
     });
     window.removeMenu();
    };

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
      //   showRecorderWindow();
    }
  });
});

module.exports = {
  window
}
```

However when I require the window using:
`const { window } = require("./window.js");` the window variable is always null. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of "setters" and "getters" will resolve your problem.

Your `main.js` file should `require` your `window.js` module and `create()` the window.

If any other Javascript file(s) requires access to the window instance then within that file you can `require` the `window.js` module and then just call the `get()` function.

---

Within your `main.js` (main thread) file:

1. `require` the `window.js` file which contains the `create` and `get` functions.
2. Declare the `window` variable so it is not garbage collected.
3. On `electronApp.on('ready', ...)` allocate to the window variable the created window instance.

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

const appWindow = require(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'window'));

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = appWindow.create();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        appWindow.create();
    }
});
```

---

Within your `window.js` (main thread) file:

1. Create 2 functions - One to `create` the window and one to `get` the window instance.
2. Export both functions for use elsewhere.

```js
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require('path');

let window; // Top level scope within the module

function create() {
    window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window; // Return the instance of the window
}

function get() {
    return window; // Return the instance of the window
}

// Export the publicly available functions.
module.exports = {create, get};
```

---

And finally, when you need to refer to the instance of `window` in `another.js` (main thread) file:

1. `require` the `window.js` file.
2. Call the `get()` function.

```js
const nodePath = require('path');

const appWindow = require(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'window'));

let window = appWindow.get();
```

This is really handy when you need to use a specific window as a parent to a child window or dialog.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `module.exports = <object>`, you are creating a copy of the object with no link back to the original object. In your code, the `module.exports` section is run before the window is created in the `app.whenReady()` section. This is because your function in the `app.whenReady()` section is run asynchronously. So at the time `module.exports = { window }` is run, `window` still equals `null`. To fix this you need to move `module.exports` into `app.whenReady()` after `createWindow()` or, to fix the scoping, into `createWindow()` like so (I also corrected the indentation):

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

const createWindow = () => {
  if (window) return;
  const window = new BrowserWindow({
    minWidth: 820,
    minHeight: 620,
    width: 820,
    height: 620,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  });
  window.removeMenu();
  module.exports = {
    window
  }
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow(); 
  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
      //   showRecorderWindow();
    }
  });
});
```

Now when you require `windows.js` it will return the latest `window` object. Just make sure to do your `const { window } = require("./window.js");` once the app is ready:

```
// file2.js

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

let window = null;

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (window == null) {
      { window } = require("./window.js");
    }
  });
});
```

Note that you can't `require("./window.js")` multiple times to get the latest window as node.js will hold a copy of window.js when you require it. You may also want to look into inter-process communication: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc

Comment: Interesting approach. I've had trouble with trying to use `require()` in conditional blocks like this; I think it clashed with whatever webpack was doing? The getter approach (the other answer) was my first thought, and might be more reliable.